# After computer upgrade streaming media is choppy

Tags: 11.04, streaming

I just upgraded my computer to: 
AMD x4 955, 
Mobo: MSI 970a-G45 AM#3+ socket,
GPU: XFX ATI 6870.

After I upgraded I reinstalled 11.04.  Now whenever I go to any live streaming media site like justin.tv or ustream for example, it is never a good stream.  It is constantly choppy and stalls.  I've run speed tests and gotten good marks, but when downloading from the ubuntu server for upgrade I manage ~30kb/s, not sure if this is related.

I've installed adobe flash, uninstalled it, installed gnash, but no luck.  Installed restricted drivers for the GPU.  All of this also happens in Mint.

Onboard lan is Realtek 8111E.  PCI wifi G card doesn't help either.

Done some searching, but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

30 kb/s or even 30 kB/s is not enough speed to stream videos continuously. You will have to pause a video as soon as it starts buffering and wait for it to buffer for a while before you play it.